# How to rebind TAB and RET in an Emacs minor mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, keymapping

I am trying to define my minor mode, mimicking it after `isearch-mode` (since it is kind of an interactive search-and-replace tool, I thought it might be a good starting point).  My commands work well (tested on global keybindings), but I have serious problems with binding them locally (in the minor mode map) to some keys, namely TAB and RET.  I'm doing something like this:

```
(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "\s" 'my-command)
    (define-key map "\t" 'another-one)
    (define-key map "\r" 'yet-another)
    map))
```

(Of course, I *did* put my keymap into minor-mode-map-alist.)

While the space-bound command works fine, TAB and RET somehow do not.  If I change, eg, "\t" to "[f11]", it works fine.  I tried using the "vector notation" ([?\t]) with identical results (after C-h C-v-ing my keymap it was not surprising).  What might be happening?

**Edit:** to clarify the problem, I tried to isolate it and I came up with the following code.  Assume that I want to have an artificial, rather minimal minor mode `tabbang` in which the TAB key inserts an exclamation mark.  I'm doing this:

```
(defvar tabbang-mode)
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-alist '(tabbang-mode tabbang-mode) t)

(defvar tabbang-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [?\t] 'tabbang-insert-bang)
    (define-key map [?\C-\t] 'tabbang-insert-bang)
    (define-key map [f11] 'tabbang-insert-bang)
    (define-key map [?\r] 'tabbang-done)
    (define-key map [t] 'tabbang-other-char)
    map))
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist `(tabbang-mode . ,tabbang-mode-map) t)

(defun tabbang-insert-bang ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "!"))

(defun tabbang-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (setq tabbang-mode " tabbang"))

(defun tabbang-other-char ()
  (interactive)
  (tabbang-done)
  (setq unread-command-events
    (append (listify-key-sequence (this-command-keys))
        unread-command-events)))

(defun tabbang-done ()
  (interactive)
  (setq tabbang-mode nil))
```

While in my `tabbang-mode`, "other" keys correctly exit the mode and insert themselves, f11 inserts a bang (correct), TAB does not exit the mode (correct), but inserts nothing (wrong), C-TAB yields "undefined key" error (definitely wrong), and RET exits the mode (correct), but inserts a newline (wrong).  And I tried on a "fresh" emacs (without loading site-file and my .emacs), so that no other code should intervene (I was afraid of yasnippet somehow capturing TAB etc.)  What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can change them with `(kbd "<tab>")` and `(kbd "<return>")` in place of "\t" and "\r" respectively.

---

In response to your edit, yes, the following works perfectly for me:

```
...
(defvar tabbang-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "<tab>") 'tabbang-insert-bang)
    (define-key map (kbd "<C-tab>") 'tabbang-insert-bang)
    (define-key map (kbd "<f11>") 'tabbang-insert-bang)
    (define-key map (kbd "<return>") 'tabbang-done)
    (define-key map (kbd "t") 'tabbang-other-char)
    map))
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist `(tabbang-mode . ,tabbang-mode-map) t)
...
```

Comment: That's not correct; I think you mean `(kbd "<tab>)` and `(kbd "<return>)`.

Comment: Right.  Apart from that - I don't want to bind C-TAB, I want TAB!  (And I have problems with C-TAB either, in a minute I'm going to edit the question to reflect that.)

Comment: Whoops. Yup, I accidentally added the `C`s. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, it works!  The only sad thing is that I have no idea (i) why this works and my solution didn't and (ii) how do I know what strings define what keys (I guess that looking at the source of the `kbd` macro might help, though).  But thanks a lot anyway!!!

Comment: @mbork - you should be able to find out what string is associated with a key by using `M-x describe-key` (`C-h k [your key]`). That will either give you the message `[your key] is undefined` in the minibuffer, or it will open up a new buffer describing which function is associated with the key. In either case, it will coincidentally tell you what string you need to pass `kbd` to specify that key.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the following: some keys get translated via function-key-map, which only performs the translation when the key would otherwise be unbound.  E.g. the [tab] event generated under GUIs when you hit to the TAB key, gets translated to [?\t] if there is no binding to [tab].  Same thing for [return], which gets mapped to [?\r].  Now the problem is that your catchall [t] binding means that any key sequence has a binding, so [tab] is not remapped to [?\t] any more.
isearch suffers from the same problem, see the contortions we do in isearch-other-meta-char.

I think the right approach to this problem is to avoid the [t] binding and instead implement the "exit mode for any other key" in a different way (my rule of thumb nowadays is: "if you need to put things back on unread-command-events, you're probably doing it wrong").  One way to do it is to use a pre-command-hook that checks whether `this-command' is one of yours, or whether (this-command-keys-vector) is bound in your keymap.  In Emacs-24, we'll probably have something like the code below for those kinds of uses:

```
(defun set-temporary-overlay-map (map &optional keep-pred)
  (let* ((clearfunsym (make-symbol "clear-temporary-overlay-map"))
         (overlaysym (make-symbol "t"))
         (alist (list (cons overlaysym map)))
         (clearfun
          `(lambda ()
             (unless ,(cond ((null keep-pred) nil)
                            ((eq t keep-pred)
                             `(eq this-command
                                  (lookup-key ',map
                                              (this-command-keys-vector))))
                            (t `(funcall ',keep-pred)))
               (remove-hook 'pre-command-hook ',clearfunsym)
               (setq emulation-mode-map-alists
                     (delq ',alist emulation-mode-map-alists))))))
    (set overlaysym overlaysym)
    (fset clearfunsym clearfun)
    (add-hook 'pre-command-hook clearfunsym)
    (push alist emulation-mode-map-alists)))
```

Comment: Why do you set overlaysym to overlaysym?

Comment: Just learned that the symbol's value needs to be set for the temporary map to be active.

Answer (score 0):

The string "tab" (that is, what you get with `"\t"`) does not correspond to a valid key name.  You want something like `"\C-i"` for tab and `"\C-j"` for newline.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I tried with `[?\t]`, too, and both syntaxes yielded something like `(9 . my-command)` in the keymap, so I suppose I did this part correctly.  Anyway, using `"\C-i"` gives the same entry in the keymap anyway (and it doesn't work).